# Firestore Error: too much contention on these documents, please try again

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google Cloud Firestore to save some documents using a Python script. In Cloud Firestore, my data is divided up into collections and documents. Documents point to subcollections that contain other documents (collection group).
I execute multiple write operations as a single batch ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to documentation), but sometimes I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 690, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 592, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.ABORTED
    details = "Too much contention on these documents. Please try again."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1587693610.322629065","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:173.194.76.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1055,"grpc_message":"Too much contention on these documents. Please try again.","grpc_status":10}"
```

The function I use to save my collection group documents is the following:

```
from google.cloud import firestore  #1.6.0
import time

def save(docs):
    """saving in Firestore using collection_group"""

    #chunk of 500 (batch commit does not support more than 500 savings at a time)
    docs_chunk=[docs[i:i+499] for i in range(0, len(docs), 500)]
    db = firestore.Client()
    for c in docs_chunk:
        batch = db.batch()
        for doc in c:
            c = db.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('DOCUMENT_NAME').collection('SUB_COLLECTION_NAME').document('SUB_DOCUMENT_NAME')
            batch.set(c, doc)
        batch.commit()
        time.sleep(5)
```

What does this error mean? Sometimes, if I re-run the script, the error does not occur any more.

Comment: You probably exceeded one of the limits as described in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices

Comment: None of the limits have been exceeded. Unfortunately I get the same error